# Period in Path Name

Tags: scripting, applescript

I'm having a compiler error whilst trying to navigate to the path of an external script, this is because I have a period in my username. Does anyone know the proper syntax to get around this in AppleScript?
This is the code I'm using to set the path name as a string:

```
set thePropertyScriptPath to (path to /Users/firstname.lastname/Desktop) & "Properties.scpt"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it need to be in there and not just path to desktop?

```
set thePropertyScriptPath to path to desktop folder as text
set thePropertyScriptPath to (thePropertyScriptPath & "Properties.scpt") as string
```

Comment: As string and as text are the same. No need for as string in second line... also no need for (). It should read set thePropertyScriptPath to thePropertyScriptPath & "Properties.scpt"

Comment: Better yet... set thePropertyScriptPath to (path to desktop as text) & "Properties.scpt"

Comment: This was what I first wrote and it failed... set thePropertyScriptPath to (path to desktop as text) & "Properties.scpt"

Comment: How did it fail? What is the message?

Comment: Was going from memory there, but your line works now that I'm back on a mac.. not sure exactly what I tested.